# Programmatic navigation in Ionic React using ExploreContainer template

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router, capacitor, ionic-react

I'm using the side menu template from Ionic React, so most of my logic is in ExploreContainer.tsx .

```
//imports

//some logic

const ExploreContainer: React.FC<ContainerProps> = ({ name }) => {
  switch( name ) {  //switch to show content on requested item from side menu
    case 'Home':
      return (
        //content for home
      );
    case 'Info':
      return (
        //content for info
      );
  }
};

export default ExploreContainer;
```

Now, since I'm building this for mobile, I'm using Capacitor. This enables me to listen for hardware back button events. When the user presses their back button, I want them to back taken back to 'Home' in this example.
All answers I have found kind of always refer to buttons for navigation, where it's possible to declare a custom state and maybe use the `<Redirect />` component.

Now, to extend the former example, lets say I want something like this:

```
//imports
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
    
const ExploreContainer: React.FC<ContainerProps> = ({ name }) => {

  Plugins.App.addListener("backButton", () => {
    name = "Home";
  }

  switch( name ) {  //switch to show content on requested item from side menu
    case 'Home':
      return (
        //content for home
      );
    case 'Info':
      return (
        //content for info
      );
  }
};

export default ExploreContainer;
```

Sadly, this does not work. Previously I've tried the following:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

Plugins.App.addListener("backButton", () => {
  history.push("/page/Home");
});
```

This however leads to some really ugly behavior. The app completely reloads, all variables are reset, etc.

If I understand correctly, the `name` property of the `ExploreContainer` is a state that gets changed when the user selects an item from the menu, so normally the app doesn't need to reload.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score -1):

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const history = useHistory();

Plugins.App.addListener("backButton", () => {
  history.push("/page/Home");
});
```

Comment: " This however leads to some really ugly behavior. The app completely reloads, all variables are reset, etc. "